# Erlang : Is there a function to remove all nested elements from a list?

Tags: erlang

I have this kind of list:

```
[[[[{a,2},{s,w}],{e,1}],{d,l}]]
```

Is there a function that will remove all of the tuples so they are all on the same level? Like:

```
[{a,2},{s,w},{e,1},{d,l}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`flatten/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1) from the `lists` module.

```
lists:flatten([[[[{a,2},{s,w}],{e,1}],{d,l}]]).
```